# Warning : Deactivation of this APK will result in your app being available for new installs on fewer types of devices

Tags: android, google-play, android-build

I have one version of app uploaded on Playstore with different architecture and now I want to upload my app with new version but getting.

> Error:
> You can't rollout this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added APKs.

And also getting some warning error like

> Device support removed
>
> Warning
>
> Deactivation of this APK will result in your app being available for
> new installs on fewer types of devices.
>
> Tip
>
> If this is an unintended change, then retain this APK in the new
> release or ensure that your new APKs support all currently supported
> devices.

Right now,

```
Minimum API level : 16
Maximum API level : 26
```

and Earlier, it was

```
Minimum API level : 11
Maximum API level : 21
```

Anyone have any idea how to resolve this error ?

Comment: i think you should change application versionCode and versionName .!

Comment: Did you increment the versionCode in your gradle file (module:app), and also did you use the same .jks file as previous version, while creating new release version.

Comment: @ Danger Yes updated the versionCode and versionName and earlier I had generated certificate in eclipse and using the same certificate in studio

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/6296561

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because you increased `minimum api` level from 11 to 16, so some of your potential users with `android 16-` can not update their application.

**Update**

> I cannot decrease the api level due to some library used Is there any solution to resolve this error

To answer your question, you can upload multiple `apk` in `play store`. One with old libraries that support `minSdk 11` and one with new libraries and possibly new functionalities that supports `minSdk 16`. You can find the required guides [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)

Comment: I cannot decrease the api level due to some library used Is there any solution to resolve this error?

Comment: @Himadri I have updated my answer to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I had uploaded mulitple apk with different architecture. By handling version code properly for all apk has resolved my problem

Comment: @Himadri Glad that it worked for you. As it solved the problem, please mark my answer as  accepted answer then.

Comment: @Merka i've same error, but my min api is same as previous release rollout.

Comment: @Merka even I am getting same warning though I have not incremented min API level.

Comment: @Tara what changes you had in your build.gradle? Did you for example change the max api level? Or anything else?

Comment: no. not even max APi level as well. only version code and name change. Apart from this few URL changes or library updates

Comment: @Tara maybe some of the libraries that you are using now, have higher min api level. It is just s guess, can you check it?

Comment: ok will check it. Thanks for your support. But incase if they are using it then!!