# I getting this error while publish application to playstore

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my Warning message while publish  my application to playstore.

Device support removed
Warning:

Deactivation of this APK will result in your app being available for new installs on fewer types of devices.

Tip:

If this is an unintended change, then retain this APK in the new release or ensure that your new APKs support all currently supported devices.

This is my SDKversion
       minSdkVersion 21
       targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49443602/warning-deactivation-of-this-apk-will-result-in-your-app-being-available-for-n?rq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098392/error-while-uploading-apk-on-playstore

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/6296561

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you increased minimum api level from 11 to 16, so some of your potential users with android 16- can not update their application.

Update

I cannot decrease the api level due to some library used Is there any solution to resolve this error

To answer your question, you can upload multiple apk in play store. One with old libraries that support minSdk 11 and one with new libraries and possibly new functionalities that supports minSdk 16. You can find the required guides here

Comment: Is there any problem, to ignore this warning and start Rollout to production?

Comment: Library which supports high api level wont work . but google itself shows the error if api level is min and need to increase

Comment: I did not increase this level and am getting this error.